# Impersonating an administrator to access the virtual directory to save files

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, webserver

I am forced to impersonate someone so that I can use :

```
Server.MapPath("~\dirname\");
```

And save files there, else I get a permissions related error. So I thought impersonating the administrator account.

```
<identity impersonate="true"
        userName="domain\administrator"
        password="*********" />
```

But since this website/app will be used by our customers, is this a potential security risk? If it is, what should I be doing in this case? All I am trying to save is some Excel files.

Comment: "impersonating the administrator account" ... " is this a potential security risk?" ... yes

Comment: Why not read/write yourself on their behalf?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you'll want to take a look at the App Pool and check which account that is using.  You can give write permissions to the specific folder for only that account and avoid impersonation altogether.

Comment: Is it better to change the identity of the Pool or the website itself?

Comment: Changing the Pool *does* change the website.  If you impersonate, then you are overriding the Pool settings.  If you run only one site per Pool, then it's your choice.

Comment: "look at the App Pool and check which account that is using" -- sorry how do I check this? In the "application pool defaults" dialog the identity is "ApplicationPoolIdentity" which doesnt correspond to anything inside the "Permissions" -> "security" tab of the website. But I do see a username called "Portal" which is the same name as my website...

Comment: [Configuring Application Pools in IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2a231dcb-d786-4b6d-b3ba-bda04061a5e7.mspx?mfr=true) or [Managing Application Pools in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753449%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should not give your iis user the rights of admin on your system. If you have any coding errors your users will be admin on your system. To do this right give the iis user the rights to write and read in the directory.